# Control motor brushless with esc using jetson nano

Tags: python, gpio, nvidia-jetson-nano, motordriver, motorengine

I have done a lot of research on how to control a brushless motor with an ESC (Electronic Speed Controller) using a nano jetson. I did not find how to connect the esc to the gpio of the jetson.
I also did not find how to make a simple code to control my motor.

If you could help me to clear these points.

Thanks in advance.

Sacha Lepresle

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Nvidia [Jetson GPIO repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-gpio), and the [PWM sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-gpio/blob/master/samples/simple_pwm.py). You could for example initiate the PWM-signal to 100Hz like this:

p = GPIO.PWM(output_pin, 100)

And adjust the PWM duty cycle between 0.1-0.2% in order to generate the necessary 1-2ms high pulse PPM signal to set, like this:

```
p.ChangeDutyCycle(0.1) # 0%
p.ChangeDutyCycle(0.2) # 100%
```

I am uncertain if the resolution of the Jetson Nano PWM-timers are good enough for this kind of small adjustments, but it is a quick thing to try.